# Grade calculator using dictionary

Tags: python

The arrays I am given are...

```
grade_scale = {
    'A+': {'low': 96, 'high': 100, 'gpa': 4.0},
    'A': {'low': 93, 'high': 95, 'gpa': 4.0},
    'A-': {'low': 90, 'high': 92, 'gpa': 3.7},
    'B+': {'low': 86, 'high': 89, 'gpa': 3.3},
    'B': {'low': 83, 'high': 85, 'gpa': 3.0},}

student123 = {
  "id": "smith123",
  "classes" : [
    {"name": "stats 100",   "points": 88, "credits": 4},
    {"name": "cs 101",      "points": 92, "credits": 3},
    {"name": "history 101", "points": 91, "credits": 3},
    {"name": "Pysch 201",   "points": 86, "credits": 4},
  ]
}
```

Please bear with me on my coding, I am brand new to coding languages.
My intuition is creating:

```
def get_letter_grade_v1(grade_scale, gpa):
  for (grade, data) in grade_scale.items():
    if gpa >= data['gpa']:
      return grade
    elif gpa <= data['gpa']:
      return 

    else: 
      return 'D'
#print(get_letter_grade_v1(grade_scale, 3.47))
```

I can't seem to get further than this without getting more lost.  It is a function with two parameters grade_scale and a gpa (in that order) and it returns the letter grade.  If the gpa is so low that it's below a 1.7, return a 'D'.

Answer (score 0):

You should return `grade` whenever the given `gpa` reaches the standard for a grade being iterated, and return `D` only after the loop ends without a return:

```
def get_letter_grade_v1(grade_scale, gpa):
    for grade, data in grade_scale.items():
        if gpa >= data['gpa']:
            return grade
    return 'D'
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have already pointed out the flaw in your `if` statement.  You have another large problem in that you are passing the wrong value into the function.  You need to convert the score, not a GPA, to a letter.

Also, depending on your Python version, you may not get your dict elements iterated in the order you expect.  As a safety measure, check both ends of the range.

```
student123 = {
  "id": "smith123",
  "classes" : [
    {"name": "stats 100",   "points": 88, "credits": 4},
    {"name": "cs 101",      "points": 92, "credits": 3},
    {"name": "history 101", "points": 91, "credits": 3},
    {"name": "Pysch 201",   "points": 86, "credits": 4},
    {"name": "XYZ 864",     "points": 66, "credits": 1},
  ]
}

def get_letter_grade_v1(grade_scale, gpa):
  for (grade, data) in grade_scale.items():
    if data['low'] <= gpa <= data['high']:
      return grade

  return 'D'


for course in student123["classes"]:
    print(course["name"], get_letter_grade_v1(grade_scale, course["points"]))
```

Output:

```
stats 100 B+
cs 101 A-
history 101 A-
Pysch 201 B+
XYZ 864 D
```